# Incompatible pointer types initializing __strong with an expression of NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, core-data

So I'm pretty noob when it comes to Core Data.  I have two NSManagedObjects, Map and AddressAnnotation.  In one of my ViewControllers, I do this:

```
Map *aMap = (NSManagedObject *)[self.address map];
```

And I get the warning

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Map *__strong' with an expression of 'NSManagedObject *'
```

Why do I get this warning?  Thanks!

Edit:
Declaration of the address property:
@property (nonatomic, strong) AddressAnnotation *address;

Comment: Remove the cast to `(NSManagedObject *)`.

Comment: @Martin R without the cast I still get the same warning.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `address` property and the contents of the generated files "Map.h" and "AddressAnnotation.h"?

Comment: Is `Map` a known class? Did you `#import "Map.h"`? This sounds like the compiler thinks a `Map*` and an `NSManagedObject*` are two separate types of pointers, rather than just two separate types of objects.

Comment: Do you use the Xcode-generated files Map.h/AddressAnnotation.h? Can you show their contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Map` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, you are asking the compiler to implicitly downcast. (`NSManagedObject` to `Map`). All instances of `Map` are `NSManagedObject`, but the reverse isn't necessarily true... Cast to `id` or `Map*` instead.

Comment: Also why is `-map` not returning a map instead of a managed object instance?

Comment: oh ok, that makes sense.  I got confused being new to Core Data and I thought I just wanted a Map object vs a NSManagedObject.